# Angular RxJS, replay HTTP request

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I am looking for a way to replay my http/get request on demand, for instance after a post to update my data from server. I was looking at repeat or expand operators, but not sure this is the right path.  What is the recommanded pattern ?

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
const data$ = this.http.get<Todo[]>(url);
data$.subscribe(console.log);
// wait 5 sec for instance, then replay the http get again and get data$ updated
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timer` for emit a event each 5 seconds and then use a higher-order mapping like `switchMap` to request the data.

```js
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
const data$ = this.http.get<Todo[]>(url);
const dataWithTimer$ = timer(0, 5000).pipe(switchMap(() => data$))
dataWithTimer$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yasser's answer, I will finally go to :

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';
const webData$ = this.http.get<Todo[]>(url);
const force$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
const forcedData$ = force$.pipe(switchMap((b) => webData$));
forcedData$.subscribe(console.log);
setTimeout(() => force$.next(true), 5000);
```

I can use the force update manually then